# PyDICOM can't read pixel data and needs GDCM or Pillow

Tags: python, python-imaging-library, pydicom, gdcm

I'm using `pydicom` and my code is pretty straightforward:

```
image = np.stack([s.pixel_array for s in scans])
```

But this gives a runtime error:

```
RuntimeError: The following handlers are available to decode the pixel data however they are missing required dependencies: GDCM (req. GDCM), Pillow (req. Pillow)
```

I'm not sure what to do. Any help would be.. helpful.

Comment: For any compressed pixel data, pydicom uses an external library to decompress the data.  As indicated, you need to install either GDCM or Pillow to handle that particular file.

Comment: I’m having an impossible time installing it: https://stackoverflow.com/q/54676488/239879

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If GDCM is giving you problems, give Pillow a go.
`python -m pip install pillow`
Make sure to install in the correct environment.

Answer (score 3):

I have encountered the same problem and I already had `pillow` installed. The solution was to update `pydicom` and install `gdcm` (see [here](https://sourceforge.net/p/gdcm/gdcm/ci/master/tree/INSTALL.txt)) as pointed out in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50725792/no-available-image-handler-could-decode-this-transfer-syntax-jpeg-lossless-when) by *@Ali Türkay Avci*. Using anaconda, you do:

```py
conda install -c conda-forge gdcm
```

Answer (score 2):

Installing python-gdcm solved my problem

```
pip install python-gdcm
```