# How can I install GDCM with the Python wrapper?

Tags: python, pipenv, gdcm

I'm on Ubuntu 16.04 and have been trying like crazy to install GDCM so I can use it with Python. I have `pipenv` installed, and I suspect that's causing issues.

I did `sudo apt-get install libgdcm2.6 python-gdcm`. It seems to install fine, but when I run `python` and then `import gdcm`, it complains there's no module named `gdcm`.

Has anyone come across this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This means that the python cannot find the gdcm package within its environment. So your package is not installed properly, and/or your environment has not been configured correctly.
Try the following:

- remove pipenv
- make sure "import gdcm" works with a 'normal' python environment.

if it does not work you know the problem lies (also) somewhere else:

- make sure your PYTHONPATH is set correctly and that gdcm is located there (see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5199346/2878353))
- Once it works in your normal environment make sure  [you have read and understand the pipenv documentation](https://pipenv.readthedocs.io/en/latest/diagnose/#no-module-named-module-name)  and reinstall pipenv and configure your environment