# JPEG2000 Losses Read DICOM in Python 3.7

Tags: dicom, jpeg2000, pydicom, gdcm

In my Python 3.7, I want to read DICOM. But I face this notification:

> NotImplementedError: this transfer syntax JPEG 2000 Image Compression
>   (Lossless Only), can not be read because Pillow lacks the jpeg 2000
>   decoder plugin.

I've tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50725792/no-available-image-handler-could-decode-this-transfer-syntax-jpeg-lossless-when) solution, but anaconda prompt gives me this:

> > failed
> >
> > UnsatisfiableError: The following specifications were found to be in
> >     conflict:
> >       - gdcm -> python=3.6 -> python_abi=[build=*_cp36m] -> pypy[version='<0a0']
> >       - python=3.7
>
> Use "conda search  --info" to see the dependencies for each
>   package.

What should I do?

Comment: What pydicom version you are using, and on what system?

Comment: I'm using Windows 10 and I've updated Pydicom into 1.4.2

Comment: Did you use `conda install gdcm -c conda-forge` to [install GDCM](https://pydicom.github.io/pydicom/dev/tutorials/installation.html#installing-gdcm)?

Comment: Yes, I did. But it gives me error that I've provided in this question.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not an expert in conda, but it doesn't look like there are  [any versions](https://anaconda.org/conda-forge/gdcm/files) of GDCM available on conda forge for Windows with Python 3.7+, you'll need to stick with 3.6.

If you want to use Pillow with the JPEG2k plugin with conda then you should `conda install -c conda-forge openjpeg` before installing pillow (see the [pydicom installation instructions](https://pydicom.github.io/pydicom/stable/tutorials/installation.html#installing-pillow)).